# Perl: regex substitution with case-sensitive backreference

Tags: regex, perl, backreference

Can you help me find a perl one-liner that can do a find/replace as follows:

Find:     **a**somestring
Replace:  **b**somestring

Find:     **A**somestring
Replace:  **B**somestring

essentially need to somehow backreference what case the original text was and replace it with different text, but same case. (case backreference for just the first character)

Thanks!!

Comment: "Gimme code" isn't generally how this works. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sorry I'm brand new to stackoverflow. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
s/([mM])ark/ ( $1 eq 'm' ? 'j' : 'J' ) . 'oseph' /eg
```

or

```
my %repl = (
   'mark' => 'joseph',
   'Mark' => 'Joseph',
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %repl;
my $re = qr/$pat/;

s/($re)/$repl{$1}/g;
```

Comment: I didn't know about the /e modifier.  Perfect, thanks!

Comment: It makes the replacement expression a callback. Basically, `s{...}{...}` is short for `s{...}{ qq{...} }e`

Comment: interesting.

how would it be if "somestring" was different for both instances, kinda like: 
(I should've been clearer) 

find: matt replace: joseph
find: Matt replace: Joseph

Comment: @geekyclimber - Use a hash if you're going that route.

Comment: Adjusted. . . .